# Managing multiple settings.py files

Tags: python, django, apache, deployment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to manage local vs production settings in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626326/how-to-manage-local-vs-production-settings-in-django)

I have managed to deploy successfully a **Django project** on **Apache's Web Server** with `mod_wsgi`.

I would like some recommendations on how to manage multiple `settings.py` files. Right now I have one for development and one totally different for production (regarding DB parameters, static content localization, and stuff like that). My `settings.py` file is versioned (don't know if this is a good practise) and I deploy it with something like:

```
$ hg archive myproject.tbz2
$ cd /path/of/apache/web/project/location
$ bzip2 -db /home/myself/myproject/myproject.tbz2 | tar -xvf -
```

It's working OK. But I find myself manipulating multiple `settings.py` files.

I guess my question is: what are the best practices when deploying **DJANGO PROJECTS** regarding multiple `settings.py` file versions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to manage local vs production settings in Django?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626326/how-to-manage-local-vs-production-settings-in-django)  or [Django database settings for production server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887851/django-database-settings-for-production-server)  or [Django dynamic settings infrastructure and best practices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109352/django-dynamic-settings-infrastructure-and-best-practices)

Comment: Thanks Ned. I would vote to close my own question. The first one you mentioned has the answer I am looking for. Thanks again.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I use a settings module that is not a single file:

```
settings/
    __init__.py
    _base.py
    _servers.py
    development.py
    production.py
    testing.py
```

The `__init__.py` file is simple:

```
from _servers import get_server_type
exec("from %s import *" % get_server_type())
```

The `_base.py` file contains all of the common settings across all server types.

The `_servers.py` file contains a function `get_server_type()` that uses `socket.gethostname()` to determine what type of server the current machine is: it returns `development`, `production` or `testing`.

Then the other files look a bit like (`production.py`):

```
DEBUG=False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG=False
from _base import *
```

In each of these files, I put in the settings that only apply to this server type.

Comment: Very clever approach. I am learning a lot with this question. As might have guessed, I am doing my first steps in DJANGO... :-)

Answer (score 9):

The trick that seems to be the most common is to maintain both a settings.py and local_settings.py (one for each environment) file.

Environment agnostic settings go into settings.py and at the bottom of the file, you'll import from local_settings.py

```
try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

You can override any settings.py settings in the appropriate local_settings.py

Comment: Awesome tip jboutros. Thanks. Will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 7):

*django-admin.py* / *manage.py* both accept a `--settings=mysite.settings` option.  In development you could explicitly specify `--settings=dev_settings`.  You can also set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODUL`E environment variable in your apache configuration.

Personally, I simply don't check in settings.py.  Instead I check in multiple settings files (dev_settings, prod_settings, etc) and symbolically link them to *settings.py* as desired.  This way if I simply checkout my application it won't be runnable until I think about which settings file is appropriate and actually put that settings file in place.

Another suggestion I've heard but I don't particularly like is having a *settings.py* that dynamically imports a *dev_settings.py* if it exists.  While this may be more convenient I'd be concerned that it's harder to read *settings.py* and know what the settings will actually be without also looking for overriding values in a *dev_settings.py* file that may or may not exist.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Your answer was really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

My preferred way is to load a separate ini file using ConfigParser, based off a single setting or environment variable. Anyway in the django wiki there are many different options described: http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings

Comment: See also my expanded answer to the question marked as possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9517763/384417