# Set variable on shub deploy project

Tags: python, deployment, scrapy, environment, scrapinghub

I'm trying to setup scrapy settings to work with test and production environment on local and also on scrapinghub.
And I would like to know if there is any way to set this variable (for example as the following) on shub deploy:

[image]

And then at settings.py:

```
if env == "test":
     var1 = some_ip
     var2 = username
elif env == "prod":
     var1 = some_ip
     var2 = username
```

Or... maybe there is a cleaner way to this?

Thank you for reading!

PS: I want to automate the settings depending of the environment where is the spider/project located instead of changing the variables manually.

### EDIT: Found a better solution. Check [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47305956/6371926).

Comment: `scrapinghub` platform offers you to setup the project settings on their UI

Comment: @eLRuLL I wanted to select settings dynamically by depending where the spider is executed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I solved my problem following these steps:

- Implement [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5161213/6371926).

So now my settings look like this:

[image: settings tree]

- And then my `__init__.py` look like this:

[image: __init__.py file]

- Next, modified `_environment.py` as the following:

[image: _environment.py. this is a function helper that gets programmatically the environment where is Scrapy at the moment]

I hope I have been helpful!

PS: Remember that you need to have two projects on scrapinghub, one for production and one for testing to do this, also you need to deploy from the same project as the following:

[image: scrapinghub.yml]

And then you just have to ([reference](http://shub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deploying.html?highlight=scrapinghub.yml#deploying-dependencies)):

- `shub deploy test` Deploys to test.
- `shub deploy prod` Deploys to production.
- `shub deploy` Deploys to test.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to control it using environment variables you could do the following: export an environment variable `DEPLOY_TARGET` that would contain `test` or `prod` and execute the following command to deploy

```
shub deploy $DEPLOY_TARGET
```

Comment: That helped me to thinking on environment variables but did not solved my problem. Thank you anyways!